# How to calculate check digits for a Hexadecimal IMEI (Number+Character) using luhn's algorithm?

Tags: luhn

I want to understand the logic so that I can implement this algorithm in java.
I want to calculate check digit for a valid hexadecimal IMEI number.
For example - 6C4BFFC0000004
Please help me with the algorithm.
I tried to find solution in google but I could not find correct answer using those algorithm.

[Calculation what I did is like -](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiDnz.png)

But the check digit for the above IMEI is 4. I am getting 7. I dont know where I am going wrong.

Comment: _"a valid hexadecimal IMEI number"_ Which standard would that be? Or are you talking about _MEID_ numbers?

Comment: you must convert to decimal first

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you do not need to convert to Decimal first. If you have an "IMEI" in hex it is really an MEID. IMEIs are a decimal-only subset of MEIDs. There is actually a patent out on how to calculate the Luhn for hex-based MEIDs. See claims 0113 through 0119 of the following:

https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/74/63/03/3fb507952c7ccf/US20080194223A1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same need and I found the solution by using the logic explained on the following website :

[Luhn test of credit card numbers](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers)

I write a function based on the C example in order to determine the last digit. Behavior will be the same in Java.